# ASP.NEt MVC 3.0 Pass Int Array as Parameter from Ajax ActionLink to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, named-parameters

can i pass an Int Array from Ajax.ActionLink (from  my View) to Controller as  a parameter

this is my view

---

```
@{
int [] IDArray = ViewBag.AllIds;
}

 @Ajax.ActionLink("send", "SendtoSS", new { id= IDArray }, new AjaxOptions
{
OnBegin = "Routing",
UpdateTargetId = "dialog-model",
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
}, new { @class = "button" })
```

In my Controller

```
public ActionResult SendtoSS(int[] ID)
    {
}
```

Comment: Where is IDArray defined?  And are you aware you have a closing square bracket but no opening one?

Comment: I have my array in the View, Please see the question i have modified with more details. when i try this my ActionResult function in Controller received null value. but when i insert break point in my View and check that Ajax link is have IDArray with values

Comment: More details: on my action like is rendered as this http://localhost:80/SendtoSS?ID=System.Int32%5B%5D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I was not able to find a solution to pass an array.
what i did was, in my view i have converted my Array of IDs to a String with a coma for each ID and in my controller i receive string parameter and convert back to array.
this has solved my problem for now.

But i would like to know if we can pass an array as a parameter through action link